# How to add space in grouping of multiple JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Grid extends JFrame {
    public Grid() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2));
        pnl.add(new JButton("One"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Two"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Three"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Four"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Five"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("1"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("2"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("3"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("4"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("5"));
        this.add(pnl);
        this.setTitle("Grid");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 75);
        this.setLocation(200, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grid app = new Grid();
    }
}
```

how to add space **between** five and 1

like this picts:

[image: images]

I'm already trying to resolve this with `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` but nothing happend, its will be give space every button

Comment: Did you try the `GridLayout` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-int-int-) that declares four parameters?

Comment: If you want empty slots in the grid of a GridLayout, use JLabels with a one space label.  In your picture above, that would be 3 blank JLabels.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is the same as the code in the question but uses the `GridLayout` constructor that declares four parameters, namely:

- number of rows
- number of columns
- horizontal gap between columns (in pixels)
- vertical gap between rows (in pixels)

```java
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Grid extends JFrame {
    public Grid() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2, 10, 10));
        pnl.add(new JButton("One"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Two"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Three"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Four"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("Five"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("1"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("2"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("3"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("4"));
        pnl.add(new JButton("5"));
        this.add(pnl);
        this.setTitle("Grid");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 75);
        this.setLocation(200, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grid grid = new Grid();
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the running app.

[image: grid]

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add border to every jcomponent with the setBorder-method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: Given a button already has several borders which change according to whether it is pressed, focused etc., it does not pay to mess with them unless removing them completely (and that is only *rarely* a good idea). To get extra space with borders *without* interfering with the button's preexisting borders, add them to a `JPanel` and set (for an example relevant to the question) an `EmptyBorder`. But Abra has already shown how to add extra space between the buttons using the grid layout constructor, which is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You add space to group `JButtons` by adding dummy `JLabels`.

Here's an example GUI.

[image: Grid Layout Example]

1. You should start all Swing applications with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I separated the `JFrame` code from the `JPanel` code.  This allows me to focus on one part of the GUI at a time.
3. I set the location of the `JFrame` based on the platform.
4. I set the preferred size of the `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` will size itself based on the JPanel size.

Here's the minimum, runnable, example code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridLayoutExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createControlPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        panel.add(new JButton("One"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Two"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Three"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Four"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Five"));

        panel.add(new JLabel(" "));
        panel.add(new JLabel(" "));
        panel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        panel.add(new JButton("1"));
        panel.add(new JButton("2"));
        panel.add(new JButton("3"));
        panel.add(new JButton("4"));
        panel.add(new JButton("5"));

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use 2 panel and 2 FlowLayout for each one of panels, if you want something like your images

Comment: 1) `LinearLayout` is Android based, not Swing / AWT. 2) *"you can give size to your buttons too"* Well, **don't** because a) it's just a guess, & b) it will be typically ignored by the layout manager. Buttons *can* be resized in various ways, but that's not one of them, and it's not necessary here in any case.

Comment: Yes i meant flowLayout but head crossed. Thanks. But i still think, the only thing needed here is two different panel. And 5 buttons on each one of them. Also, at the beginning, without how to use any layout, i was just giving size and pixels to buttons and it is never a best way to do it but it always works to me.

Comment: 1) *"but it always works to me"* That's fine if you are the only user of that software, but.. (one of my copy/paste comments): Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) *"Yes i meant flowLayout but head crossed."* You can [edit] an answer at any time..

Comment: thanks for the infos about g,v,ng size to buttons etc. Yes, i always used it on one OS and with 1 user , when i give size to buttons. I edited it :)

Comment: *"..i always used it on one OS and with 1 user"* Please refrain from giving Swing layout advice, for all the reasons I set out starting with *"Java GUIs have to work on.."*.